# Should I install a subfloor if I'm putting LVP in my basement?

Tags: basement, subfloor, vinyl-flooring, basement-refinishing

I live in an area with temperatures from -7°F to 118°F. I'd like to put Luxury Vinyl Plank (LVP) in my concrete basement, but I've heard conflicting reports on if I need a subfloor.

Some assumptions:

- If I installed a subfloor, I'd be putting down moisture barrier. I'll be using DRICORE as an example as its got OSB and a moisture barrier built as a single piece.
- With LVP, all the ones I've looked at come with an underlayment.

## Moisture

If I use DRICORE subflooring, that supposedly gives me a moisture barrier.

Since the subfloor itself is OSB wood, is it possible for moisture to get trapped between it and the LVP since the LVP would have a rubber or plastic underlayment?

## Leveling

My basement slab isn't 100% level; although, the dips are minor. From what I've seen, it's mostly an issue of sloping like most basements.

From seeing DRICORE installation videos, they have special shims available to help level the floor to some degree. This would prevent needing to patch the concrete and allow the LVP to sit flat.

Unlike carpet, my assumption is that you'd want a hard floor to be completely flat as dips would be noticeable.

## R Value

A subfloor, especially DRICORE, adds R value from 1.44 to 3.00. I don't know if this is important as LVP doesn't let heat transfer as much as other materials. Is it going to be a major improvement to comfortably?

## Question

I'd like to know on which points I'm right and wrong and any gotchas I made not have considered using LVP with a subfloor in a basement.